# Error, polytonic Greek spell file

Tags: spell-checking

Is anyone using the polytonic Greek spell file successfully? I get `Error detected while processing /Users/lawrence/.vim/spell/polytonic.utf-8.spl:
E763: Word characters differ between spell files`.

PS. Sorry, I was impræcise before: I get this error only when combining Greek with English, after `set spell` and `set spelllang=polytonic,en_gb` (regardless of whether in .vimrc or session). It works fine, though; but the error message is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I followed instructions as described at [github](https://github.com/vim-scripts/polytonic.utf-8.spl). This is the result.

[image]

Only way I could reproduce the behaviour mentioned previously was when I haven't `set spell` in my `.vimrc`  but tried to enable spelling in open Vim through command.

So maybe that is what is missing. Another possible explanation may be that there is an error in your file, so try to download it from github, and set it again.